# App not using all cores on VM after migrating host

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, migration, central-processing-unit, multi-threading

We have a DL380 G7 with 2x Xeon E5645 processors running at 2.4Ghz, on which we had ESXi 4.1 installed with a few VMs.

One of our VMs had Windows Server 2008 R2, with 4x vCPU and 12GB RAM. This was used for our accounts staff to run their reporting add-in for Excel.

We have just migrated the VM to a different DL380 G7 running 2x E5620 also at 2.4Ghz

I have made no changes to the config of the VM, so it still has 4x vCPU and 12GB RAM. However, when the users run their Excel reporting tool now, it looks to only be using on of the 4 vCPUs, causing the report to take forever to run.

Is there any part of the migration process that could have caused the VM to not correctly assign threads to each core?

Comment: Are you sure it was using all it's vCPUs on the previous host? Also, ESXi 4.1, I think it's time to upgarde!

Comment: One thing to investigate that I had a problem with recently on Excel is that it does not multitask due the nature of the program however it can run concurrent queries across multiple CPU's. However it has been known to not run them on Cores (so one socket four cores it will only use a single core) change that to One Core and Four Sockets see if you get better results...

Comment: Yes definitely well over due an upgrade. We are in the process of moving to 5.5 as we speak, but need to keep this running for a while longer. I am almost certain it was using multiple cores previously, although I didn't actively monitor it that often, as there was never a problem. I will give the multiple sockets suggestion a try, and see what happens. I'll also be opening a case with the software vendor for some advice.